# Excel - SumIF Cell Value is between date range & another Cell is False

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need help writing a formula to do the following

> Sum the value of cells that fall withing a specified date range BUT
>   only if the corresponding cell range A3:A21 is False

I have the current formula that handles just the date range comparison.

```
=SUMIFS(H3:H21,I3:I21,">="&'Essential Info'!A9,I3:I21,"<="&'Essential Info'!B9)
```

- Cells A9 on Essential Info handle the date for the start of the week,
- Cells B9 on Essential Info handle the date for the end of the week,
- H3:H21 Contains the number values to be added,
- I3:I21 Contains the Date Values to be compared to A9 & B9 on Essential info.
- A3:A21 Contains a true or false value based on a tick box.

I am falling over at the "If Cell Range is false" part.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to append your formula with this `, A3:A21, "false")`.

Comment: =SUMIFS(H3:H21,I3:I21,">="&'Essential Info'!A9,I3:I21,"<="&'Essential Info'!B9, B3:B21,FALSE)

Comment: Welcome, is it working properly?  And it is always helpful if while posting questions,you can share the pic of the some of the data

Comment: Working perfectly thank you. Unfortunately the data was a bit hard to censor out the sensitive parts in this scenario. I will try to provide more information in future. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use Sum product Instead of sum ifs:

```
=Sumproduct((I3:I21>='Essential Info'!A9)*(I3:I21>='Essential Info'!B9)*H3:H21)
```

Comment: This is fine for normal sum ranges but excludes the "If A3:A21 is false, do not add" issue. I appreciate the input though. Above solution works perfectly for my purpose